# ListView similar to iOS

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Want to achieve this in Android using ListView and data from cursor (result set returned by a database query).

Popular cities are identified by a flag in the database.

[image: Screen layout]
Any suggestion, ideas or third party library would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the List View as Indexable. You can check the below link which I used as well to achieve the same.

Complete library source:
https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView

Particular class source:
https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView/blob/master/src/com/woozzu/android/widget/IndexableListView.java

Comment: It was somehow helpful to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use customized ExpandableListView and show your data in sorted order by alphabetically. You have to take care about both Group view as well Child view.

Answer (score 0):

Just use section indexes! They're built into ListView